# Generate dates from csv file - missing values generated

Tags: csv, stata

I have a dataset imported from a .csv file in which there is a variable called date, that shows dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy. When working in Excel, this variable is correctly formatted as date.

However, when I try to make Stata recognize this variable, it generates only missing values. I use the command

```
generate data_n = date(date,"DMY")
```

The variable is imported as a string by the program.

Comment: Please show us an example. You're describing your problem and not giving us the means to reproduce it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve applies.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems. `test.csv` file:

```
date,x
"25/10/2015",1
"26/10/2015",2
```

Stata (version 14) commands:

```
import delimited test.csv, delim(",") varnames(1) clear
* or insheet using test.csv, clear
generate date_n = date(date,"DMY")
format %td date_n
list
```

Result:

```
. list

     +----------------------------+
     |       date   x      date_n |
     |----------------------------|
  1. | 25/10/2015   1   25oct2015 |
  2. | 26/10/2015   2   26oct2015 |
     +----------------------------+
```